# Get the string value from List<String> through loop for display

Tags: java, android

I'm confused about on how to use this array in a way that is simple. Well I already passed the values from the JSON into a List and now I need to retrieve it using a loop (and just loop) but I don't know how. Tried reading some answers but I found myself really confused in the end. I just want it to be simple as making a String array, loop and fetch data by getting the variable[index] simple as that but all the answers I've found just lead me into confusion. Help please.

Comment: Do you need more than a foreach? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ForeachArray.htm

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As I understand your question..

From Java [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) class you have to methods `add(E e)` and `get(int position)`.

```
add(E e)
```

Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional operation).

```
get(int index)
```

Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

**Example:**

```
List<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();

// How you add your data in string list
myString.add("Test 1");
myString.add("Test 2");
myString.add("Test 3");
myString.add("Test 4");

// retrieving data from string list array in for loop
for (int i=0;i < myString.size();i++)
{
  Log.i("Value of element "+i,myString.get(i));
}
```

But efficient way to iterate thru loop

```
for (String value : myString)
{
  Log.i("Value of element ",value);
}
```

Comment: already tried this one sir. hmm. Let me see. I'm going backing checking my JSON parsing maybe that part is the one that gives me a problem. will go back on you later. Thanks!

Comment: This one helps me and it's much simple. Anyway helps me to notice that I forgot to add the permission of internet access in my android Manifest. haha! Sounds crazy but this answer really helps me notice it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
    ls.add("1");
    ls.add("2");
    ls.add("3");
    ls.add("4");

//Then  you can use "foreache" loop to iterate.

    for(String item:ls){
        System.out.println(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. but I still prefer the answer of user370305 due to being noob friendly. Yeah I'm the noob one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the For-Each loop which came with Java 1.5, and it work on Types which are iterable.**

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("Vivek");
data.add("Vadodara");
data.add("Engineer");
data.add("Feelance");

for (String s : data){

 System.out.prinln("Data of "+data.indexOf(s)+" "+s);

 }
```

Comment: Your answer is just the same as user370305 gives. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well if the problem is about iterating over a collection the answer will be same, but i think u missed the line in bold, thats gives a very important info, and i think user370305 didnt gave it...

Comment: And both the above answer are using for loop, where i am using the for each, the question was about iterating over the collection, so how come its same ???

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra : I think you have missed something , I've used for each loop .

Comment: I see, anyway will review all of this answer later. Still back tracking on my codes. Thanks for all of your answers.

Comment: Yes i missed to see your answer, but i think it was for the use370305, with whom my answer was compared, secondly you missed the line i wrote before my answer, which tell when for-each is applicable

Comment: Haha! don't be so rough sir. Sorry if ever you feel offended by my comments. Well I already solved the problem and I think that's it, case closed. Thanks for the help I will make sure to make this a reference in my future codes. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following if your looking for while loop implementation.

```
List<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();

// How you add your data in string list
myString.add("Test 1");
myString.add("Test 2");
myString.add("Test 3");
myString.add("Test 4");

int i = 0;
while (i < myString.size()) {
    System.out.println(myString.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer if you only want to use for each loop ..

```
for (WebElement s : options) {
    int i = options.indexOf(s);
    System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> al=new ArrayList<string>();
al.add("One");
al.add("Two");
al.add("Three");

for(String al1:al) //for each construct
{
System.out.println(al1);
}
```

O/p will be

```
One
Two
Three
```

Answer (score 0):

pst = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet=  pst.executeQuery(query);

```
     String str1 = "<table>";
     int i = 1;
    while(resultSet.next()) {
             str1+= "</tr><td>"+i+"</td>"+
             "<td>"+resultSet.getString("first_name")+"</td>"+
             "<td>"+resultSet.getString("last_name")+"</td>"+
             "<td>"+resultSet.getString("email_id")+"</td>"+
             "<td>"+resultSet.getString("dob") +"</td>"+

             "</tr>";
        i++;

    }
        str1 =str1+"<table>";

    model.addAttribute("list",str1);

    return "userlist";  //Sending to views .jsp
```